# Testing flask_wtf/wtforms with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, flask-wtforms

I'd like to test a POST route that processes a non-trivial form (by working with flask.request.form). I didn't really find a good tutorial for this somehow as most pass json data rather than form (or is it the same?).

I tried to write the code in the following way:

```
import pytest
import app #app.app is the Flask app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.app.config['TESTING'] = True

    with app.app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app.app_context():
            yield client


def test_route_webapp_post(client):
    form = app.forms.ImputeForm.make_form(data_dict=app.data_dictionary.data_dict,
                                        numeric_fields=app.binaries_dict['numeric_mappers'].keys(),
                                        recordname2description=app.binaries_dict['recordname2description'])
    rv = client.post('/web_app',form=form)
    assert rv.status_code==200
```

The form is generated dynamically and I don't always know ahead of time what are the fields:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField, DecimalField, BooleanField

class ImputeForm(FlaskForm):

    @classmethod
    def make_form(cls, data_dict, numeric_fields, recordname2description, request_form=None):

        for key in numeric_fields:

            setattr(cls, key, DecimalField(id=key, label=recordname2description[key].split('(')[0]))
            setattr(cls, 'mask_' + key, BooleanField(label='mask_' + key))

        for key in data_dict:

            setattr(cls, key, SelectField(id=key, label=recordname2description[key],
                                          choices=[(-1, 'None selected')]+list(data_dict[key].items())))
            setattr(cls, 'mask_' + key, BooleanField(label='mask_' + key))


        instance = cls(request_form)
        return instance
```

But this doesn't really work as I can't make a form inside the test case and get

```
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.
```

So what is the proper approach to testing my form (in particular I am ok with sending an empty one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to create a python dictionary and pass it as "data", not to try to create a form.

In particular case this involved making a new function:

```
def make_from_data( data_dict, numeric_fields):

    data = dict()

    for key in numeric_fields:

        data[key]='234'
        data['mask_' + key]='y'

    for key in data_dict:

        data[key]=-1
        data['mask_' + key]='y'

    return data
```

and passing it as follows:

```
def test_route_webapp_post(client):

    data = make_from_data(data_dict=app.data_dictionary.data_dict,
                                    numeric_fields=app.binaries_dict['numeric_mappers'].keys())
    rv = client.post('/web_app',data=data)
    assert rv.status_code==200
```